# Where to find the Qt Location addon for Qt 5 beta 2?

Tags: c++, qt, geolocation, maps, openstreetmap

I am trying to compile qtm-geoservices-extras under Qt5 beta 2, but miss some headers like:

```
qgeoserviceproviderplugin_osm.h:46: Error:qgeoserviceproviderfactory.h: No such file or directory
```

Accordingly to the online documentation this headers are part of the Qt Location addon and should be in the Qt5 SDK:

http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/5.0/location-plugin-nokia.html
http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/5.0/qgeoserviceproviderfactory.html

Does someone know where to find the Qt Location addon for Qt5?

Answer (score 0):

The Qt location add-on was removed from the Qt 5 distribution in Beta 2. It is now considered an optional [add-on](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Qt-Add-ons-Modules) module. The source code is available from the Qt project git [server](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtlocation).

Answer (score 0):

You need download the qtlocation add-on and put the package in Qt5 distribution packages dir, and reconfigure the qt and make